# 1C 8.3. Как определить, где рассчитывается поле НДС?

Tags: 1с

1C 8.3. Как определить, где рассчитывается поле НДС, если нет его события? (с помощью которой мы понимали бы, где произошло изменение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Замер производительности, локальные переменные, табло и стек вызовов долго. Если ли какой-нибудь способ, с помощью которой бы быстро находили расчет поля "НДС" (и любого другого поля)?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно пересчет данных строки табличной части производится по событию ПриИзменении колонки; Например изменилость Количество / Цена / Сумма пересчитываем значение других колонок и вычисляем НДС; (см. событие ПриИзменении этих колонок)

Кроме этого, сама табличная часть имеет событие ПриИзменении ;